# What is the best practice of copying from array to array in Solidity?

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity, truffle, remix

I am trying to save gas by optimize code. In a flash, however, I was wondered what is the best practice of copying from array to array in Solidity.

I present two option. One is copying by pointer (I guess) and the other is using for-loop.

**TestOne.sol**

```
contract TestContract {
    uint32[4] testArray;

    constructor(uint32[4] memory seeds) {
        testArray = seeds; // execution costs: 152253
    }

    function Show() public returns (uint32[4] memory) {
        return testArray;
    }
}
```

**TestTwo.sol**

```
contract TestContract {
    uint32[4] testArray;

    constructor(uint32[4] memory seeds) {
        for(uint i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            testArray[i] = seeds[i];  // execution costs: 150792
        }
    }

    function Show() public returns (uint32[4] memory) {
        return testArray;
    }
}
```

I tested with Remix (Ethereum Online IDE), 0.8.13 Solidity Compiler with Enable optimization (200)

### Discussion of test result

We can see that, TestOne used **152253 gas** for execution costs, and TestTwo used **150792 gas** for execution costs.

The funny thing is that, **for-loop** used less gas than just assigning pointer. In my little thought, for-loop would be more assembly codes than the other. (There would be, at least, assigning `uint i`, substitute 4 times, check conditions 4 times (whether `i < 4`), increase `i++` 4 times etc.)

I suspected the "optimization" of solidity compiler. But, after doing same small experiment without "Enable optimization", it does same result that for-loop used less gas. (198846 vs. 198464)

### The Question is

1. Why do above things happened?
2. What is the best practice of copying from array to array? Is there any copy function like C++'s `std::copy()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice is copy array from memory to storage without looping over their items. However contract optimization in this example is tricky. The [official documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/using-the-compiler.html#optimizer-options) says as follow:

> If you want the initial contract deployment to be cheaper and the later function executions to be more expensive, set it to `--optimize-runs=1`. If you expect many transactions and do not care for higher deployment cost and output size, set `--optimize-runs` to a high number.

To illustrate above, consider following contracts:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

contract TestLoop {
    uint32[4] testArray;

    function setArrayWithLoop(uint32[4] memory array) public {
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            testArray[i] = array[i];
    }

    function setArrayWithoutLoop(uint32[4] memory array) public {
        testArray = array;
    }

    function show() public view returns (uint32[4] memory) {
        return testArray;
    }
}

contract NoLoop {
    uint32[4] testArray;

    constructor(uint32[4] memory array) {
        testArray = array;
    }

    function show() public view returns (uint32[4] memory) {
        return testArray;
    }
}

contract Loop {
    uint32[4] testArray;

    constructor (uint32[4] memory array) {
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            testArray[i] = array[i];
    }

    function show() public view returns (uint32[4] memory) {
        return testArray;
    }
}
```

and script written by using `brownie`:

```py
from brownie import TestLoop, NoLoop, Loop, accounts

def function_calls():
    contract = TestLoop.deploy({'from': accounts[0]})
    print('set array in loop')
    contract.setArrayWithLoop([1, 2, 3, 4], {'from': accounts[1]})
    print('array ', contract.show(), '\n\n')

    print('set array by copy from memory to storage')
    contract.setArrayWithoutLoop([10, 9, 8, 7], {'from': accounts[2]})
    print('array ', contract.show(), '\n\n')

def deploy_no_loop():
    print('deploy NoLoop contract')
    contract = NoLoop.deploy([21, 22, 23, 24], {'from': accounts[3]})
    print('array ', contract.show(), '\n\n')

def deploy_loop():
    print('deploy Loop contract')
    contract = Loop.deploy([31, 32, 33, 34], {'from': accounts[3]})
    print('array ', contract.show(), '\n\n')

def main():
    function_calls()
    deploy_no_loop()
    deploy_loop()
```

with following `brownie-config.yaml`:

```yaml
compiler:
  solc:
    version: 0.8.13
    optimizer:
      enabled: true
      runs: 1
```

which gives following outputs:

```sh
Running 'scripts/test_loop.py::main'...
Transaction sent: 0x8380ef4abff179f08ba9704826fc44961d212e5ee10952ed3904b5ec7828c928
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 0
  TestLoop.constructor confirmed   Block: 1   Gas used: 251810 (2.10%)
  TestLoop deployed at: 0x3194cBDC3dbcd3E11a07892e7bA5c3394048Cc87

set array in loop
Transaction sent: 0xfe72d6c878a980a9eeefee1dccdd0fe8214ee4772ab68ff0ac2b72708b7ab946
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 0
  TestLoop.setArrayWithLoop confirmed   Block: 2   Gas used: 49454 (0.41%)

array  (1, 2, 3, 4) 


set array by copy from memory to storage
Transaction sent: 0x0106d1a7e37b155993a6d32d5cc9dc67696a55acd1cf29d2ed9dba0770436b98
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 0
  TestLoop.setArrayWithoutLoop confirmed   Block: 3   Gas used: 41283 (0.34%)

array  (10, 9, 8, 7) 


deploy NoLoop contract
Transaction sent: 0x55ddded68300bb8f11b3b43580c58fed3431a2823bf3f82f0081c7bfce66f34d
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 0
  NoLoop.constructor confirmed   Block: 4   Gas used: 160753 (1.34%)
  NoLoop deployed at: 0x7CA3dB74F7b6cd8D6Db1D34dEc2eA3c89a3417ec

array  (21, 22, 23, 24) 


deploy Loop contract
Transaction sent: 0x1aa64f2cd527983df84cfdca5cfd7a281ff904cca227629ec8b0b29db561c043
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 1
  Loop.constructor confirmed   Block: 5   Gas used: 153692 (1.28%)
  Loop deployed at: 0x2fb0fE4F05B7C8576F60A5BEEE35c23632Dc0C27

array  (31, 32, 33, 34)
```

#### Conclusions

1. When we consider contract function call optimization, then usage of memory to storage copy, [here is more info](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour), is more gas efficient than copy by for loop. Compare `gas used` from function `setArrayWithoutLoop` and function `setArrayWithLoop`.
2. When we consider contract deployment optimization it seems there is opposite situation to this in conclusion 1.
3. **Most important**: Contract constructor is called only once in contract lifetime, just when the contract is deployed to chain. So the most often there is an function call optimization rather than contract deployment optimization. This leads to conclusion 1.